# Did Anakin Skywalker draw upon the Dark Side when he slaughtered the Sand People?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, anakin-skywalker

Did Anakin Skywalker draw upon the dark side of the Force when he slaughtered the Sand People?

The question says it all. Did he use the dark side of the Force and (assuming he did) did he *know* he was using the dark side?

Comment: Huh? Can you clarify? If I understand your question, and I'm not sure that I do, it sounds like you've already answered it.

Comment: @rosesunhill Umm, did Anakin use the Dark Side side in any way when slaughtered the Sand People. I can't get much clearer than that bud.

Comment: I would assume that they answer is yes, as he is using his anger snd hatred for power, but I curently have no proof

Comment: What are the secondary questions about?

Comment: @rosesunhill Do you speak the King's English friend?

Comment: The sub-question about Palpatine is a bit of a dupe of [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76735/why-didnt-anakin-face-any-repercussions-for-killing-the-entire-village-of-sand?rq=1). He shared his entire experience with him, albeit not knowing that he was a Sith Lord

Comment: Let's not go there. I asked an honest question. The secondary questions seemed, well, secondary. And that's all I'm going to say about it. I don't want a flame war.

Comment: @rosesunhill Did Palp know at the time it happened through the force., Mr. Sensitive?

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker - Palpatine can sense the dark side (since he's powerful in the dark side). Also, he's been watching Anakin. Also, Anakin told him about the encounter, albeit without realising that Palpatine has been subtly pointing him toward the dark side for nearly his whole life.

Comment: related http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110679/54827

Comment: "Anger. Fear. Aggression. The Dark Side are they." -- Yoda. If the vengeful massacre of an entire tribe of sandpeople doesn't qualify as anger and aggression, I'm not sure what does. Also, sandpeople are reasonably tough fighters, and Anakin was greatly outnumbered. He was using the Force to beat them, and it sure wasn't the light side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely he did draw upon the dark side of the Force. We have a couple of sources for this;

From the (fully Disney-canon) [Star Wars in 100 Scenes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_in_100_Scenes).

> Anakin searches the desert wastes for his mother. **His quest ends in
> grief and pain, leading to rage fuelled by the dark side of the Force.**
> The episode is a glimpse of the future: Anakin's inability to master
> his emotions will lead to tragedy for himself and those he loves

and from within the [Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(novel)), it's pretty obvious that his Force abilities are being enhanced by his anger and hatred

> *At that time, the only meaning, the only purpose, that Anakin could
> fathom was that of the rage building within him, an anger at losing
> someone he did not wish to give up.*
>
> ***Some small part of him warned him not to give in to that anger, warned
> him that such emotions were of the dark side.***
>
> ... [Anakin kills a bunch of Sandpeople using the Force and his lightsaber]
>
> *And then he was running, his strides enhanced by the Force, overcoming
> the fleeing creatures, slaughtering them, every one.*
>
> *He didn’t feel empty any longer. **He felt a surge of energy and
> strength beyond anything he had ever known, felt full of the Force,
> full of power,** full of life.*

Comment: Excellent answer as always. Nailed it.

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker - I cheated and started writing it before you'd posted it :-)

Comment: I thought perhaps that was the case. Still good though.