# Did Darth Vader really turn to the light side?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, darth-vader

Vader’s goal was to rule the galaxy. The emperor stood in his way. He killed the emperor. How does that qualify him as turning to the light side? Because he declares he is now on the light side?

He kills thousands of innocent Padawans, unknown number of other beings. Utters one sentence about turning to light side and it’s all good? Pretty sketchy.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/97618/76048

Comment: @F1Krazy - Seems like an almost exact duplicate to me. Certainly the other answers address this in great detail.