# Before Darth Vader died in Episode VI did he revert back to the light side of the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, darth-vader

A colleauge and I are in disagreement. Before Darth Vader died in Episode VI did he revert back to the light side of the Force? I have aggressively argued that he did not as it was only a momentary realisation of his errors and could have been a feign attempt at gaining some form of redemption. Whereas my colleague, who favours *Star Trek* to *Star Wars* and doesn't understand the intricacies of the Force, believes that he had in fact transcended sides.

It took Anakin years to be completely consumed by the dark side, yet Vader made the same switcheroo in 2 minutes? Questionable to say the least.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did Vader saving Luke turn him to the good side?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97618/how-did-vader-saving-luke-turn-him-to-the-good-side)

Comment: So do you agree that in the end Vader transcended to the good side?

Comment: The answers for the linked question about Sith becoming Force Ghosts show that, in canon, it is not possible for a Sith to become a Force Ghost. Therefore, since we see Anakin's Force Ghost it must be that he turned back to the light before he died. One of the answers to the linked question about Anakin learning to become a Force Ghost includes a quote by George Lucas indicating that Anakin/Vader died as Anakin (hence, on the light side).

Comment: “doesn't understand the intricacies of...” ...a made-up concept created and developed by dozens of authors over 42 years and counting.

Comment: Yes there is someone who doesn't understand.  You.  It's made 100% clear in ROTJ that Vader was redeemed.  Ignoring for a moment that they changed the scene to use the wrong actor, we see that he is back together with his buddies in the force ghosts scene.